# Visual Studio don't call Application_End on Debug

Tags: asp.net

I implement some code in Application_Start and Application_End (global.asax).
When i start ASP.NET Developer Server the Application_Start run normally.
When i change the web.config file, the method Application_Start is called again but Application_End is never called.

Someone know how can i force Application_End run before the second call to Application_Start

Comment: When do you expect it to be called?

Comment: @Oded After i change the web.config and save it.

Comment: The problem happens only when i add my complex code, inside the events. If i just add some Trace the events are called correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code opens a server socket in Application_Start, so Visual Studio couldn´t restart my application whitout closing it. 
For safety VS don´t restart my Application.

VS calls Application_End only if he knows that noone is affected.
In my case i could be using the socket to sending or receiving data.

Answer (score 0):

Is Application_End not being called or is it that a break point in Application_End is not being hit?

Application_End is called when the application pool is stopped.

When you are debugging you are attached to the application pool process.

What may be happening is that the debugger looses contact with the application pool before the Application_End is called, and you are therefore not hitting the break point.

Comment: Like i said in one comment, the problem is very strange.
When i add my code (that open sockets etc.) in Start and End event, the Start event is called only once.
When i add only a Trace.WriteLine() and save, the web.config, the End and Start event are called normally.

Comment: Then the question is what is in your complex code. Try putting it in a few lines at a time and see when it stops working.

Comment: I opened some listeners and sockets. But no one was using the socket when i saved the web.config file.
The question is, when VS decide to call Applicaton_Start?

Comment: Application_Start is run whenever the app pool starts